# Bad practice to embed a React component in Navbar?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, components, navbar

Is it bad practice to embed a `Results` page component in the `Navbar` component since it has the search bar in it and I could pass the input value as a prop to `Results` component in the JSX? But is this good practice as I am including a major component in the Navbar? Currently, I am using the router, `useNavigation`, `useParams`, methods to detect change but it is introducing unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Questions about bad practices are almost always opinionated and off-topic. Instead, you should ask about your actual concerns.

Comment: Every app is different, "bad practice" generally only applies to certain code practices/methods rather than component hierarchy. It's up to you whether that structure makes sense for your use-case, and it's unlikely we will be able to provide any helpful opinions.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure that its just a design choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Okay to pass props from parent to child component.

if you think it is not good practice then use [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

or else use Global State Management library like [redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)

but for Simple Application I suggest that to pass props
from Parent to child.

Comment: Yea, I was thinking about this. That if an application were to grow or it was large, this would not be the best solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <AppContainer>
        <SearchBar value={searchString} updateSearch={...} />
        <Results searchString={searchString}/>
    </AppContainer>
```

Maybe there is a parent component that maintains the state and then pass the manipulated search as a prop to its children.